# how to load data into BigQuery with caret(^) delimiter

Tags: google-bigquery, delimited, bq-load

I have went through documentation for all the supported file types in BQ.
But I came into this issue.

Consider, I have a sample compressed file .gz with format as -

**filetype :**

```
col1^col2^col3
d1^d2^d3
```

**Command:**

```
bq load --source_format=CSV projectId:dataset.table gs://bucket/*.gz
```

when I upload the file with GUI with auto schema, it loads the data properly.
but when I try for bq load cmd it fails, saying -

**Error :**

```
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references
column position 63, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1
columns.
```

any idea about caret delimited files?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
bq load --help
```

shows that there's an option :

```
-F,--field_delimiter: The character that indicates the boundary between
    columns in the input file. "\t" and "tab" are accepted names for tab.
```

to indicate the field delimiter